# laravel 10 cors problem when deployed on a shared hosting

Tags: reactjs, laravel, cors

i built a website the frontend using react and the backend using laravel 10 then deployed the frontend part on vercel and the laravel api using a shared hosting
the website works fine when i make the requests using my localhost as a server but when i try using the backend server it gives me this error
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://mybackend.hstn.me/api/homePage' from origin 'https://easylearning-seven.vercel.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

the website worked fine before the deploying but after i deployed my website it gives me error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my JavaScript code receive a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error, while Postman does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-code-receive-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-i)

Answer (score 0):

Add Middleware

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class Cors
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response)  $next
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {
        return $next($request)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, X-Token-Auth, Authorization');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have cors file config on config/cors.php and change :

`'allowed_origins' => ['*'],`

to

`'allowed_origins' => ['https://easylearning-seven.vercel.app'],`

and you can specify more option about header within this file